# Bind9 virtual subdomains

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, bind, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to setup virtual subdomains using Bind9, following this tutorial.. http://groups.drupal.org/node/16862 which I've completed. Basically setting up the zone and modifying the resolv.conf file and the named.conf.local file.

I've gotten everything to work, and I am able to from my server ping mydomain.com , test.mydomain.com and when i do a dig I get the following..

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> test.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32606
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;test.mydomain.com.                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
test.mydomain.com. 86400   IN      A       174.###.###.#

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.com.      86400   IN      NS      mydomain.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mydomain.com.      86400   IN      A       174.###.###.#

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 19 21:06:01 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 86
```

So it looks like everything is working. However, when I try and do test.mydomain.com in the browser, expecting it to default for now to mydomain.com it does not work and I get a server not found page in Firefox.

I did read elsewhere that in your virutalhosts file you also need to setup a *.mydomain.com alias, but that didn't fix anything.

Any other information that I could provide to help troubleshoot, or any troubleshooting suggestions?

I am using Ubuntu 10.4, with typical LAMP setup. The only other things installed on the server are Bind9 and ftp client.

Answer (score 2):

If it's showing the "server not found" page in Firefox it means that you're having a local DNS issue, try to add the domain to your local hosts fie and refresh your local dns cache.

Comment: When you say local hosts you mean - /etc/hosts ? Right now I have two lines: 127.0.0.1 localhost and 174.###.###.# mydomain.com webserver

Comment: That sounds good, but you need to add test.mydomain.com to that file as well, at least until the DNS changes get replicated properly

Comment: Hmm, I want it to handle any number of subdomains, that was the point of using bind9 so I wouldn't have to manually specify a large number of subdomains. Bind9 is suppose to forward all of the requests of any subdomain like test.mydomain.com -> mydomain.com which I can then manipulate as I would like (i.e. w/virtualhost and htaccess mod rewrite rules).

Comment: No you're missing what I'm trying to say, I'm saying that somehow either your cache or your DNS server (if different from the one you have configured) haven't received the change yet :)